# keyboard is not showing when auto focus is true in flutter textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

When I restart this code in Visual Studio `autofocus` is working as well as keyboard is showing. When I close the visual studio and re open the app in android emulator the keyboard is not showing but auto focus is working (Cursor is showing).

But its work in android 5 perfectly.

My code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone fix this? Thank you.

Comment: See this (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58498) open issue on Flutter Github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting `autofocus: true` and setting the focus after a delay worked for me:

```
...

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late FocusNode myFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {focusNode.requestFocus();});
    });
  }

  ...

        child: TextField(
          focusNode: myFocusNode,
        )

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode.requestFocus();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: focusNode,
          autofocus: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working but its working in android 5..